# Create netrc for Windows (on wine)

Tags: windows, artifactory, wine, .netrc

Hi I am trying to run wine (for win 64) on docker (ubuntu) and I need to access artifactory/git from inside wine. If I were on docker, I could simply add my credentials to .netrc file. In case of wine, where should I specify these details? I know in Win environment I need _netrc instead of .netrc specified under %HOME%. But somehow, this is not read by wine.

_netrc in Windows under %HOME% was what I tried

Answer (score 0):

I just found out I need to place the _netrc file in a particular location so that wine can pick it up.
$W_DRIVE_C/users/root/_netrc